# How to insert georeferenced PNG into correct location in AutoCAD Map3D?

Tags: georeferencing, autocad, png

I have a PNG of building plans that I will need to digitize in AutoCAD Map3D. I have georeferenced the PNG in ArcGIS, which has produced a world file (.pgwx) in the same directory in which the image is stored. When I attempt to bring this image into AutoCAD using either Insert Image or Data Connect, I am prompted to specify an insertion point. It is clearly not recognizing the resource file. **How can I open a georeferenced PNG in AutoCAD Map3D in the correct location?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reaname world file to `.pgw from .pnwx`. keep both image and world in same directory with same name.

Comment: This worked. Do you know why the world file extension must be changed? Does this occur with other raster formats?

Comment: Arcgis is product of ESRI and autocad map is of autodesk. both are coded/designed to read different world file extension.e.g  if your image is jpg ..world file will be jgw in autocad and jgwx will be in arcgis suit.

Comment: Is it safe to say then that there is no standard world file format?